# Are vertical lines in a Penrose diagram timelike?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

In flat space, Penrose diagrams look something like this:

[image: penrose diagram]

Geodesics are then curved lines and null curves are straight lines at $45^{\circ}$. What would a vertical line at $r\ne 0$ represent? I think it would be a timelike curve (since it is not null and does not cross any null curves), but it reaches null infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It represents a class of timelike worldlines (noting you are suppressing a couple coordinates). It may involve arbitrary acceleration however, depending on the spacetime.